# c# label and textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

Using reg ex , I can find the matching word , so I want to replace the matching word with a text box. I am doing something like  Fill in The blanks questions . i will be getting questions from database to display as labels.

The questions will be displayed as labels but I need to user to input their answers in a text box . Is it possible to integrate label with text box?

Code here:

```
string input = TextBox1.Text;
string pattern =  Regex.Escape("[") + "(.*?)]";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Value.ToString(), "");
}
```

For example : 
Hi , how [TEXTBOX HERE] you?

Hi , how you?   <-- will be displayed in labels , while i need a textbox in label for user to input their answers.
Any advise/solutions on this? thanks

In short , is it possible to replace a text with textbox and display it on a label?

Comment: `[...]` this text is appear in label.text ah? how do you find replace string?

Comment: textbox to appear in label.text , but not sure if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Try putting on a FlowLayoutPanel:

1. A label for the text before the textbox.
2. The text box
3. A label for the text after the textbox.

The FlowLayoutPanel will make sure that they are aligned one after another.

Comment: i suppose then it will be 2 different labels right? .. i can only tied a question to a label , and a textbox control in the label for users to input answers , is that possible?

Comment: @user2376998: It is possible if you create your own custom user control, which will contain 2 labels and a text box (and any other data members that may help you), then you can bind each question to a single user control.

Comment: because some question may have 2 answers and may need more than 1 textbox

Comment: so i tot if we could replace a text word with textbox then it will be good , because i need the users to type in the questions with answers , then i display it out in labels and textboxes .. For example :
i type  , My name is John . 

i need to display it in labels as , My [TEXTBOX here] is John .

the answer is Name , so i find the word ' Name ' and replace with textbox for users to input .... thats what i am trying/want to do

Comment: This is a feature that is not supported by the label control. I think your best shot is to use a custom user control and generate the labels and text boxes on the fly. Using the FlowLayoutPanel will help you to keep them in located in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have a label pretext, a text box and another label posttext. You can then set them independently.

Comment: but is it possible to replace a text with textbox?